# Cannot run react-native application on iOS simulator

Tags: javascript, react-native, ios-simulator

I'm having trouble to run `react-native` app on iOS simulator, I'm using the command `npx react-native run-ios` and here's what I'm getting:

In the middle of the output:

```
/Users/<my username>/Documents/Work/<path>/<to>/<project>/node_modules/@react-native-community/geolocation/ios/RNCGeolocation.mm:393:23: error: property 'sourceInformation' not found on object of type 'CLLocation *'
mocked = location.sourceInformation.isSimulatedBySoftware;
                  ^
1 error generated.
```

At the end of the output:

```
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    CompileC /Users/<my username>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pixidium-bfjxgtpkwdehvjehjnczkwgxsgns/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-native-geolocation.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RNCGeolocation.o 
/Users/<my username>/Documents/Work/<path>/<to>/<project>/node_modules/@react-native-community/geolocation/ios/RNCGeolocation.mm normal x86_64 objective-c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)
```

Any ideas what might be the problem and how to solve it?